# How do I update a dynamic span using ngModel in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to update dynamic items in my Ionic app; I want to update a number (quantity) when the `addItem()` function is called. I can't figure out how to update `quantity` so that I can update each one in my list based on their key.

#### items.page.html

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of collection.items">
    <span [(ngModel)]="quantity[item.id]" name="quantity[{{ item.id }}]" ngDefaultControl>
        {{ item.quantity }}
    </span>
</ion-item>
```

#### items.page.ts

```js
quantity = [];

constructor() {}

addItem(itemId: any) {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('item_id', itemId);
    this.http
        .post('http://api.example.com/endpoint', body)
        .subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                const data = {
                    key: itemId,
                    value: response.item_quantity
                };
                // how do I get the returned value from the API
                // to display in my span?
                this.quantity.push(data);
            },
            error => {}
        );
}
```

Comment: From where `addItem()` is getting called?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Inside `on-item-sliding`, a user swipes left and taps a button which  has `(click)="addItem(item.id)`

Comment: do you have something else going on that you have removed for this example? the `[()]` notation is for two way binding but a span isn't editable. If `{{ item.quantity }}` is working for you then that's all you need?

Comment: @rtpHarry The problem I'm having is getting the value returned from `addItem()` and displaying it in the span. How do I determine which span to bind it to from inside `addItem()`?

Comment: I think you are missing the fundamentals. You are not making a value and binding it to a ui. Forget about the UI. You are building a data structure in code. That data structure is always displayed live in the front end, automatically updated by Angular to reflect the value of your code. Just worry about managing your data.

Comment: So if you have a value `this.displayName` on your class, and by chance you decide to show it using `{{ displayName }}` in the UI, it doesn't matter to you. Just manage what you want `this.displayName` to be and the UI will always show what you want. Angular uses change detection to know when to update it. So you dont make the value and then apply it to the UI. You make your data structures and they are magically displayed the next time Angular does its change detection and sees you have set something.

Comment: @rtpHarry I understand that, and I have no problems when it's a single, fixed item; my problem is that I have list of items, and each item has a span that has a quantity. I don't know how to set the quantity so that it is reflected in the proper span. So it's not just one `{{ display name }}`, but currently there's 14, and potentially more in the future, so it's all dynamic. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. I just took another look at Amir's answer below, it seems to do what I was just thinking needs to be done. The thing is you are setting an array of objects so you dont have a way of looking it up via an array `[index]`, you need to do a `find()` which needs the code in that answer. You have to search for it each time with that data structure. Could also done if you just added the quantity to the object in th collection so the data all lives together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways

One:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of collection.items">
    <span>
        {{ getItemQuantity(item.id) }}
    </span>
</ion-item>
```

Two:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of collection.items">
    <span [innerHTML]="getItemQuantity(item.id)">
    </span>
</ion-item>
```

And It is necessary to detect change in addItem call like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

public quantity: array = [];
public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef;

constructor(cdRef: ChangeDectorRef) {}

getItemQuantity(itemId: any): number {
    if (this.quantity.length === 0) {
        return 0;  
    }

    return this.quantity.find(q => q.key === itemId).value;
}

addItem(itemId: any) {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('item_id', itemId);
    this.http
        .post('http://api.example.com/endpoint', body)
        .subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                const data = {
                    key: itemId,
                    value: response.item_quantity
                };
                this.quantity.push(data);
                this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // here you need to detect change
            },
            error => {}
        );
}
```

Comment: Example one gives an error: Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. I'm also unsure of how to implement this solution. Where do I set the quantity after the API call in `addItem()`?

Comment: I think we're making this more complicated than it needs to be. All I'm trying to do is get the value returned from the API and display it in the span. `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` doesn't do anything about the value returned from the API. My code `this.quantity.push(data);` is just me playing around; I don't know what I'm doing lol